# Nesting gMSA in security group for use in ACLs

Tags: windows, active-directory, security, sql-server, security-groups

I'm trying to solve a conundrum for my DBAs and developers. We have an application that is running under a gMSA (group managed service account) identity. This application needs to access a SQL database, and we prefer to grant access by using groups whenever possible. However, when adding the gMSA to a security group that has access to the DB, SQL Server is unable to resolve the account as a member of the group. Here's the kicker: when the gMSA is added directly to the DB permissions, it works flawlessly. Are there any restrictions around nesting gMSAs in security groups that I am not aware of?

Comment: Has the gMSA logged off and logged back on again since the group membership change?

Comment: I don't know. Is the AD group marked as a security group? Also, can you talk more about there preference to Grange permissions to groups? Like, could you accomplish a similar thing by using roles in the database?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the application that connects to the SQL server?

Comment: Old, but yes, the identity and the Kerberos ticket of the gMSA and client server were both reset by restarting that server.

Comment: Managing permissions via groups makes it easier to track, manage, and audit them in one place (AD).